# Google Visualization GeoMap with Google Analytics

Tags: google-visualization, google-analytics-api

Ok, so I'm really hoping someone can help me get started, I have been able to plot pies and timelines from my google analytics data via api with google visualization. I now want to extract the data from google analytics of visits and plot a geomap. This is the geomap sample code which works

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart']});

function drawVisualization() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700],
    ['South Africa', 800]
  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347});
}


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

but of course I want to get the var 'data' from my google analytics api into such an array and plot say the top 10 popular countries based on pageviews from the last 30 days?

I believe the following query will give me what I want

```
 dimensions=ga:country
 metrics=ga:visits
 sort=-ga:visits
```

How do I get this into the proper format for the data variable to plot this geomap? If you can help me rewrite the var data so that it works, I could be the happiest man alive.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This function should take the data returned by Google Analytics, input it into a DataTable, and draw a GeoChart of the top 10 countries by visit count:

```
function drawChart(results) {
    var entries = results.feed.getEntries();
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Visits');

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([entries.getValueOf('ga:country'), parseInt(entries.getValueOf('ga:visits'))]);
    }

    // sort by visits, descending
    var sortedRows = data.getSortedRows([{column: 1, desc: true}]);
    // remove all elements after the 10th
    while (sortedRows.length > 10) {
        sortedRows.splice(10, 1);
    }
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setRows(sortedRows);

    var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    // draw the chart using the view
    geochart.draw(view, {width: 556, height: 347});
}
```

Comment: great thanks, sorry, how do I query the feed, what is the proper syntax?

Comment: Getting queries to run from Google Analytics is a rather involved procedure.  Following the instructions from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/ (for the modern API) or https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/ (for legacy applications) is your best bet for getting the query running.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the new Google Analytics SuperProxy, it simplifies the process of getting api queries into the charts api, there are still a few bugs but very simple to setup, the youtibe video on the link below will take you through the full process. https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy